# Ignoring orders of magnitude in a problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, order-of-magnitude

I am so lost in this solution to a physics problem.  In the problem I find the gravitational force on the Moon due to Earth and the gravitational force on the Moon due to the Sun

They are about  $1.99 \times 10^{20}$ N and $4.34 \times 10^{20}$ N respectively.

The net force acting on the moon is about $4.77 \times 10^{20}$ N.

It asks is the answer reasonable for both to have the same order of magnitude of force.  Which due to the large mass of the sun and the further distance it makes sense.

It says the Sun is farther from Earth than the Moon by a factor of $10^{11}$ m/$10^8$ m = $10^3$  and the Sun is much more massive by a factor of $10^{30}$ kg/$10^{23}$ kg = $10^7$
mass divided by distance squared gives $10^7/10^6 = 10$.   I am fine with the calculations so far.  But this next statement I do not understand.

It appears there is a difference of one order of magnitude so perhaps both forces shouldn't have the same magnitude,  but the text reads "We have ignored factors of 3 or more.  Yes it is reasonable."  My question is why?  What factors are they referring to?  the 1.99 before the order of magnitude?  Those are digits not factors?

Comment: Hmmm... there are a couple of strong misconceptions here... and then there is the question where the $10^{23}kg$ comes from? The mass of Earth is approx. $6\times 10^{24}kg$. The sun has a mass approx. 330,000 times that of Earth. That's a far cry from 10 million...

Comment: Wow I didn't know that.  The solution used the wrong mass for Earth I think because it says the mass of Earth is $5.98 x 10^{24}$ kg in the front cover.   The sun is $1.99 X 10^{30}$ kg so that is fine I think.  So with that adjustment the solution is wrong in the book and it should be $\frac_{10^{6}}{10^{6}}$

Comment: Sorry I ran out of time to edit.  But I get something more reasonable now.  There appears to be no order of magnitude difference between the Earth-Moon and Sun-Moon force of attraction.

Comment: That's where the strong misconceptions come into play. Both Earth and Moon are in essentially the same free falling orbit around the sun. There is no gravitational force from the sun to first order. The only "force" that acts on the Moon is a tidal force, which is basically given by the difference in distance between the Earth and the Moon and that happens to be suppressed by the ratio of 400,000km/150,000,000km, i.e. it's hundreds of times smaller than the ratio that you have calculated. In reality the situation is much more complicated than that and requires serious orbital analysis.

Comment: It is introductory to physics, I am not familiar with orbital analysis.  Isn't there gravitational force of attraction between any two objects with mass.  So why wouldn't both the moon and earth have a gravitational attraction and the sun and moon as well.    Why would it be a tidal force only?

Comment: Yeah... it sounds like one of those well meaning examples with unintended consequences. The trouble with gravity is that it's not a force. It's an acceleration. Unless there is anything to stop a body from accelerating, forces never even enter the picture. Both the Earth and the Moon are in free fall around the sun and they are also in free fall around each other. The only real forces that ever come into play here are the tidal forces which result from the fact that things that are closer to another mass are falling quicker towards it.

Comment: I thought that a force was an action capable of causing an acceleration?  So wouldn't acceleration of an object be indicative of a force by f=ma?  Again this is what I read from an introductory physics textbook.

Comment: Force causes acceleration, but here we have acceleration without a physically measurable force. To measure the force of an electric field on a charge we can connect the charge to an inertial mass and then measure the acceleration. The larger the mass, the smaller the acceleration will be. $q\vec E=m\vec a$ will hold. One can put a force gauge between the charge and the inertial mass and it will show a force. In case of gravity none of that is possible. The acceleration will always be the same, no matter what the mass is and a mass between our "charge" mass and the inertial mass will show 0.

Comment: @CuriousOne I hope there is a measurable force, specifically, the gravitational force that keeps the system in orbit.  If we're orbiting, it has been measured :) . And the moon's orbit around the sun is definitely not smooth; more of a cycloid.

Comment: @BillN: There is no measurable force in first order. There is only an acceleration. There are measurable forces in higher order.